# VBA - Map list of called scripts inside a specific folder (Text files)

Tags: vba

I have a folder (and subfolders) of "main" scripts (text files) which are calling other "Utils" scripts inside the same folder or subfolders or "Utils" scripts which are calling other "Utils" scripts and I'd like to find out whether there are scripts which are not called from the "main" scripts.
(bottom line - I'd like to delete all the non-called "utils")

- All the scripts ("Main" or "utils") has the extention of ".sx4"
- Size of scripts can be 1KB-100MB
- The calls withing a script can be to the same folder or script inside the subfolders

The output of the code should be mapping of all files inside the root folder or subfolders and
a counter of how many scripts are calling it (see the below example):

**Root folder (C:\testFolder)**
MainScript1_1.sx4 (not calling anyone)
MainScript1_2.sx4 (calling MainScript2_1.sx4, Util1_1.sx4)
MainScript2_1.sx4 (calling Util1_1.sx4 and Utils\Util1_2.sx4)
MainScript2_2.sx4 (calling Utils\Util2_1.sx4 and Utils\Util1_2.sx4)
Util1_1.sx4

**Root folder (C:\testFolder\Utils)**
Util2_1.sx4 (not calling anyone)
Util2_2.sx4 (calling Util3_1.sx4 and Util3_2.sx4)
Util3_1.sx4 (calling Util3_1.sx4 and Util3_2.sx4)
Util3_2.sx4 (not calling anyone)
Util3_3.sx4 (not calling anyone)

Output of the run

- MainScript1_1.sx4   0
- MainScript1_2.sx4   0
- MainScript2_1.sx4   1
- MainScript2_2.sx4   0
- Util1_1.sx4         2
- Utils\Util1_2.sx4   2
- Utils\Util2_1.sx4   1
- Utils\Util2_2.sx4   0
- Utils\Util3_1.sx4   2
- Utils\Util3_2.sx4   2
- Utils\Util3_3.sx4   0

Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you're having?  What have you tried, and what issues did you run into?